# Have VMWare put all files on external hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

I installed VMware to my external hard drive, but when setting up Ubuntu 64 bit it puts files on my C drive causing me to lose space, how do I force all of the files to go on my external hard drive?

Comment: Can't you manually move the file?

Comment: I do not know where they are all located.

Comment: VMWare tells you the location of the virtual machine configuration file and the Virtual HDD.

Comment: how do you find this? and if I move them will it know where they are?

Comment: Have you check the VMware website?  You can view both in the settings for the virtual machine itself, no, if you move them you have to manually update the information